# ASP.NET MVC - Merge Multiple Small Apps

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, architecture

We have a number of small ASP.NET MVC apps. All are basically a bunch of forms which capture data and store them in a SQL Server database, usually which are then loaded through to our datawarehouse and used for reporting.

We are looking to rewrite all the small applications and apply a level of consistency and good practice to each. All the applications are fairly similar and I think from a user perspective it would be better if they seemed to be part of the same large application so we were considering merging them together in some way as part of the re-write.

Our two currently preferred options seem to be:

1. Create a separate portal application which will be the users point of entry to the apps. This could have 'tiles' on the homepage, one for each of the apps (which would be registered in this parent app) and could link them through to all. In this scenario all the Apps would remain in different projects and be compiled/deployed independently. This seems to have the advantage of keeping the separate so we can make changes to an app and deploy without affecting the others. I could just pull common code out into a class library? One thing that annoys me about this is that the parent app must basically use hard coded links to link to each app.
2. I looked into using 'areas' in ASP.NET MVC and have all the small apps as different areas in one big project. This seems kindof *cleaner* in my head as they are all in one place, however it has the disadvantage of requiring the whole app deployed when any of the individual ones are changed, and I have a feeling we will run into trouble after adding a number of apps in to the mix.
3. We have a SharePoint installation and someone suggested creating the portal type app in SharePoint... This doesn't sound like the best idea to me but am willing to consider if anyone can point out advantages to this method.

Are there any recommendations on the architecture of this? Has anyone completed similar projects in the past and something worked well/not well?

We have 4 developers and we do not expect the apps to change too much once developed (except to fix potential bugs etc.). We will however plan to add new apps to the solution as time goes on.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC Areas advantage would be allowing code sharing, by refactoring the repeated redundant parts of each app to use the same infrastructure code (security, logging, data access, etc.)

But it will also mean more conflicts when merging the code initially.

Deployment concerns can be mitigated with a continuous deployment tool (there are many in the market) or if you deploy to an Azure WebApp, then deployment slots can give you a zero down time deployment.